# Proof involving 3 finite sets

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $X, Y, Z$ be three finite sets. Denote $a=|X|+|Y|+|Z|-|X \cap Y| - |Y \cap Z| - |Z \cap X|$, $b=|X \cup Y \cup Z|$, and $c=|X|+|Y|+|Z|$.

a.) Prove that $a \leq b \leq c$.

To start, I know that a < b because of the Inclusion-Exclusion principle. Since $b$ would equal $a$ IF $a$ also included the case where the intersection of $X, Y, Z$ was added back into the equation but it does not. I am not sure how to prove this in the proper language. I also know that $b=c$ because the union of three sets is also the same thing as adding the cardinality of each of them together. Again, I am not sure how to prove this in a way that satisfies proof requirements.

Comment: I apologize for that, I added my work so far.

Comment: You can only conclude that $a \leq b$ since it is possible that $|X \cap Y \cap Z| = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot conclude that $a < b$ since it is possible that $|X \cap Y \cap Z| = 0$.
\begin{align*}
a & = |X| + |Y| + |Z| - |X \cap Y| - |X \cap Z| - |Y \cap Z|\\
  & \leq |X| + |Y| + |Z| - |X \cap Y| - |X \cap Z| - |Y \cap Z| + |X \cap Y \cap Z|\\
  & = |X \cup Y \cup Z|\\
  & = b
\end{align*}
where we have used the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle in the third line.

It remains to show that $b \leq c$.  To do so, we must show that
$$|X| + |Y| + |Z| - |X \cap Y| - |X \cap Z| - |Y \cap Z| + |X \cap Y \cap Z| \leq |X| + |Y| + |Z|$$
which is equivalent to showing that 
$$|X \cap Y \cap Z| \leq |X \cap Y| + |X \cap Z| + |Y \cap Z|$$
Since $X \cap Y \cap Z \subseteq X \cap Y$, $$|X \cap Y \cap Z| \leq |X \cap Y| \leq |X \cap Y| + |X \cap Z| + |Y \cap Z|$$
from which the result follows.

For the second problem, begin with the assumption that 
$$|X| + |Y| + |Z| - |X \cap Y| - |X \cap Z| - |Y \cap Z| + |X \cap Y \cap Z| = |X| + |Y| + |Z|$$